# Receiving a NameError when using require_relative for 2 files to each other

Tags: ruby

I have 2 files within the same folder `lib`: `board.rb` and `display.rb`.

At the top of each file, I used `require relative` to require both files to each other:

- Within `board.rb` : `require_relative 'display'`
- Within `display.rb` : `require_relative 'board'`

The error message I received:

```
/Users/philipyoo/Desktop/chess/lib/display.rb:46:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Board (NameError)
from /Users/philipyoo/Desktop/game/lib/board.rb:2:in `require_relative'
from /Users/philipyoo/Desktop/game/lib/board.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from display.rb:2:in `require_relative'
from display.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I removed the `require_relative` from my `board.rb` file and everything works fine now. I'm just curious why I was getting this error when I tried requiring both to each other?

Comment: A quick test under Ruby 2.2.3 shows that the circular `require_relative` isn't itself a problem. We need to see more of the contents of your files. Are they defining classes or...?

Comment: @mwp Yup, in each file, I define a class for each. And then I have driver test code in my `display.rb` file to create a new instance of `Board` and pass this new instance of `Board` as an argument into `Display`. Once I commented out the `require_relative` in my `board.rb` file, it started working which made me think it had something to do with the circular `require_relative`

Comment: If it doesn't have to do with the circular `require_relative` then I guess it's fine. I unfortunately can't replicate the problem as I moved ahead in my code after debugging. Sorry :S   I never ran into this problem before and decided to ask

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening now. `display` requires `board`, which should define the Board class, but before it does that, it requires `display`, which moves forward with its processing (because `board` was already required, so it moves to the next line) and then can't find the Board class. I'll post a solution in a formal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `display.rb` is your "main" program, then you should require its dependencies from there. If there's a reason to require `display.rb` from `board.rb`, i.e. if you want to be able to enter the program from either file (say, for testing), it would be better to use `autoload` instead of `require` (or `require_relative`). `autoload` works by tying together class names (symbols) and filenames, and it will ensure that things are loaded once, and in the correct order.

display.rb:

```
autoload :Board, './board'

class Display
  @board = ::Board.new
end
```

board.rb:

```
autoload :Display, './display'

class Board
  @display = ::Display.new
end
```

Now it won't load `board.rb` until the `:Board` symbol is encountered, and if the `:Board` symbol has already been encountered (or `board.rb` has already been loaded), it won't do it again. Likewise for the `:Display` symbol and `display.rb`. You could still potentially get into some different race conditions, though, so just make sure to test each scenario.